# How can I know the front-end framework a site is built on?

Tags: frameworks, frontend

How can I know the front-end framework a site is built on? For example I want to know which framework the site [`https://pytorch.org/`](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/) is using.

Does anyone know a tool to do this and so what's the answer of it?

Answer (score 0):

use google chrome and open the website, right click and find inspect then navigate to sources. there you can find every one of the files in the website.